# Adjusting the text position inside customtkinter.CTkLabel with an image

Tags: tkinter, customtkinter

I have recently tried customtkinter to create a UI for my Python script. Things have been going pretty well other than being unable to slightly lower the text position inside the customtkinter.CTkLabel. Attached are the partial code and the picture of the UI output.

```
self.value_box_image = ctk.CTkImage(Image.open("temperature_box.png"), size=(280, 142))

self.temperature_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.data_frame, text="90", font=ctk.CTkFont(size=60, weight="bold"), corner_radius = 50, text_color = "black",
                                      image=self.value_box_image)
self.temperature_label.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(20, 10), sticky = "e")
```

And here is the picture
[image]

I think the temperature_label.grid(...) only changes the position of the entire label itself and not just the text inside the labe. Other than that, Temperature (*F) is part of my picture, and as you can see the value 90 is just ever so slightly off because the CTkLabel always want to put the text in the center of the image. I have tried justify = "s" and anchor = "s", nothing works. If anyone have a solution for this problem can you please share it with me.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: Try `compound="top"`.

Comment: You can create an image with the upper part only (i.e. the box with "Temperature (F)") and then use `compound="top"` to put the image above the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option of `CTkLabel` to put the text at the position you want.

However you can create an image with the upper part of the original image:

[image]

Then you can use that image and set `compound="top"` to put that image above the text.  Note that you need to set the `border` and `relief` option of the label as well in order to get the same outline effect.  However `customtkinter` does not allow you to set these two options in `CTkLabel`, so you need to set those options using the internal label widget instead:

```py
# image with the upper part of the original image
img = Image.open("temperature_banner.png")
self.value_box_image = ctk.CTkImage(img, size=(img.width, img.height))
self.temperature_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.data_frame, text="90", bg_color="white",
                                              font=ctk.CTkFont(size=60, weight="bold"),
                                              corner_radius=50, text_color="black",
                                              image=self.value_box_image)
# configure the border width, relief and compound option via the internal label widget
self.temperature_label._label.config(bd=3, relief="solid", compound="top")
self.temperature_label.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(20, 10), sticky = "e")
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, that looks amazing. To confirm, your temperature_banner.png is just a png picture with Temperature (*F), right? The surrounding borders are all generated by self.temperature_label._label.config(bd=3, relief="solid", compound="top")?

Comment: Yes the PNG has the "Temperature (*F)" and the border at the bottom. You can see in my first picture.